# Vb.net Change Pixels Colors to Transparent

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pixel

I want to replace every black pixel in "file.bmp" with transparent pixel

```
 Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap(64, 64)

    b = image.fromfile("c:/file.bmp")

        For y = 0 To 63
            For x = 0 To 63
             Dim c As New Color
              c = Color.Transparent
               If b.Getpixel(x,y) = color.Black Then
                b.SetPixel(x, y, c)
               End if
            Next

     Next
        PictureBox1.Image = b
```

exception:

> Because this evaluation could cause side effects, it will not be
>   executed until enabled by user.   System.Drawing.Color

Without breakPoint the picturebox is looks like empty.

How can I replace black pixels with transparent pixels?

Answer (score 0):

If its a bitmap you can use LockBits , manipulate the pixels and then use UnlockBits. 
See here for `a sample where it sets every third value to 255`. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx#Y1085